# Sobolev embeddings for vector-valued functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I would like to know if there is a simple extension of the standard Sobolev embeddings for functions taking values in another Euclidean space.

In particular, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary, and define $W^{k,p,j}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^m)$ to be the Sobolev space of $L^p$ functions $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with norm
$$
\|f\|_{W^{k,p,j}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^m)} = \sum_{\alpha \le k} \left[ \int_{\Omega} \|\partial^{\alpha} f(x)\|_j^p \, dx \right]^{1/p}
$$
where $\partial^{\alpha}$ indicates the weak derivative with multi-index $\alpha$.

I'm likely okay if any additional simplifying assumptions are needed. Notably, I do not need any results for the general Banach-space-valued case, which I assume could get quite technical. I saw that there is some work on $k = 1$ (see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87486/reference-request-simple-facts-about-vector-valued-sobolev-space) and also this [this master thesis](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/abschlussarbeiten/MA_Marcel_Kreuter.pdf)).

Comment: Can't you recover the embeddings for $\mathbb{R}^m$-valued Sobolev maps from the corresponding componentwise embeddings?

Comment: Both of your links are concerned with functions taking values in an *infinite-dimensional* vector space. That is much more general than what you seem to need.

Comment: @Teri Hm, maybe it is just that simple. I guess then this is just an exercise. I guess then my only question would be whether that is sharp. But maybe that is also an exercise.

Comment: What is $\Vert\cdot\Vert_j^p$? What does $j$ stand for?